# Share a 'Local' relative link to a Dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox, symbolic-link, hyperlink, sharing

We use Dropbox for business, so have extensive shared folders. I want to provide a direct link to a file, but via the local copy not by a web link.
In the particular case it is under windows in an email, but it might equally be a process document.

Something along the lines of will work if I paste to my win explore address bar but not to create a hyperlink:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Dropbox\sharedir\sharedfile.doc
```

An idea solution would be:

```
%Dropbox%\sharedir\sharedfile.doc
```

But I don't know if that kind of thing is possible? or would this have to be created on each machine for each user (nor really practical even with GP)

An ideal solution would cover mac/linux too - but obviously that's trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%Dropbox% is an environmental variable. When your run command prompt and type SET, you'll get a list of environmental variables. If you are using Outlook and send a link out as `%Dropbox%\sharedir\sharedfile.doc`, Outlook will not know how to process such a "link". Outlook does understand UNC paths and drive letters though.

In the spirit of your request, you can use an old DOS command called SUBST to assign a drive letter that needs to be common to all Dropbox users.

If this is all too complicated, you can also use Dropbox Paper or Google Drive & Docs for cloud document collaboration.

For example: `SUBST D:\ c:\users\me\dropbox\` would make your D: drive the Dropbox drive. Then in your e-mails, you could write `d:\sharedir\sharedfile.doc` in your e-mail.

```
C:\Users\me>subst /?
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.
```